# When and why do I have to use singular and plural nouns following "No"?

Tags: meaning, grammatical-number

For example:

> 1. *No student* goes to school today.
> 2. *No students* go to school today.

When and why do I have to use singular and plural nouns following "No"?

Comment: Are you asking why or when you should use one form over the other?

Comment: @zpletan: Yes. The question can be answered by explaining why and when each of them should be properly used.

Comment: Well, the question as asked is apparently not what you want to know, then. You should probably make the question more explicit.

Comment: To be honest, I can't think of any instances where the two aren't interchangeable. This is a distinction without a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that the difference runs thus (based on my usage):

- A plural form would be used for a collective decision or to stress a collective situation. *No students go to school today* implies that school has been cancelled for all students; perhaps it was a snow day or merely a weekend.
- A singular form would be used for a collection of independent decisions, most often as the basis for personal action, or to stress an individual choice or mandate. *No student goes to school today* implies that each student has made the independent choice not to go to school today; I would most often see *why should I?* tacked onto the end of it.

Comment: How'd you arrive at that?

Comment: @Kris: I second zpletan's interpretation, though I would caution that the difference between these two wordings is very slight, more a degree of shade than meaning.

Comment: I don't see any interpretation -- only a conclusion -- which is why ask.

Comment: @Kris, I arrived at it by analyzing my own use of the two forms.

Comment: We are expected to state *why* and explain that with *how*. cf. Your comment at OP and his response.

Comment: @Kris: better now?

Comment: @zpletan Certainly.